# Respuesta a una llamada http angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

Cuando ejecuto esta función:

```
 $scope.Login = function (callback) {
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Inicio.aspx/Iniciar',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: { usuario: $scope.usuario, password: $scope.password }
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function (data) {



            })
        };
```

La función iniciar devuelve un tipo bolean, el cual quiero recuperar en la parte de success para evaluar su valor pero el código no siempre accede a dicha parte.

Comment: "*el código no siempre accede a dicha parte*" ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: Me refiero a esta parte:  `$http(httpreq).success(function (data) {
--> A esta parte del código no accede siempre, y entiendo que es aqui donde debo recuperar el valor devuelto por la función.
            })`

Comment: porque veo un `aspx` en la url ? estas usando angular con `asp.net clasico`, ehh es la primera vez que lo veo, porque no lo haces con `asp.net mvc`

Comment: Si analizas la developer tool del browser, a la cual accedes con F12, puedes ver en la solapa `Network` que la llamada al WebMethod se realizo correctamente

Comment: @LeandroTuttini La llamada es correcta, cada vez que hago una llamada va a la función Iniciar pero el retorno no consigo capturarlo.

Comment: podrias publicar como es el webmethod que invocas? estas seguro que recibes un http 200 como respuesta de la llamada? es lo que menciono debes validar con el developer tools, porque puede que se llame bien pero un error este devolviendo una respuesta http diferente, quizas debas capturar el `error` del `$http`

Comment: Webmethod: `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static  Boolean Iniciar(string usuario, string password) {
            String user = usuario;
            String pass = password;


            IniciarSesion IS= new IniciarSesion ();

          Boolean iniciar =  IS.IniciarSesion(user,pass);

        
            return iniciar;

        }`

Answer (score 1):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[$http angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

capturar el `success` utiliza el `then` para tomar la promise

```
$http(httpreq).then(function(response){
   //aqui codigo sucess
   console.log(response.status);
}, function(response){
  //aqui codigo error
  console.log(response.status);
});
```

Comment: Su código funciona, aunque para que se ejecute la parte de código sucess tengo que hacer doblemente al botón que ejecuta la acción

Comment: no entendi, como es eso de `doblemente al boton` ?

Comment: Si, hago clic en el botón y no hace nada, la segunda vez que hago clic en el botón, si accede al código sucess